# How can I extend Image class?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-imaging-library

I want to extend "Image" class in PIL.

```
#module Image
def open(file): ...
class Image:
    def method1:...
    def method2:...

#module myOriginal
from Image import Image
class ExtendedImage(Image):
    def method3:...

#module test
import myOriginal
im = myOriginal.open("picture.jpg")
```

RESULT: Error.myOriginal has no attribute "open".

How can I extend Image class without rewriting open() method?

Comment: There is no open() method in the class Image.Image !?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[According to Fredrik Lundh](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2006-March/003832.html), the author of PIL:

> the Image class isn't designed to be
>   subclassed by application code.  if
>   you want custom behaviour, use a
>   delegating wrapper.

**myOriginal.py**:

To delegate individual methods:

```
class ExtendedImage(object):
    def __init__(self,img):
        self._img=img
    def method1(self):
        return self._img.method1()    #<-- ExtendedImage delegates to self._img
    def method3(self):
        ...
```

Or to delegate (almost) everything to `self._img`, you could use `__getattr__`:

```
class ExtendedImage(object):
    def __init__(self,img):
        self._img=img
    def __getattr__(self,key):
        if key == '_img':
            #  http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201010/surprising_getattr_recursion.html
            raise AttributeError()
        return getattr(self._img,key)
    def method3(self):
        print('Hiya!')
```

**test.py:**

```
import Image
import myOriginal
im = myOriginal.ExtendedImage(Image.open("picture.jpg"))
im.method3()
```