# Can the python image module be extended?

Tags: python, class

Can the python Image module be extended ?
Basically its a class I think and I want to have added a numpy array representation of the image.

If I know how to extend it, then I can add all other extensions I wish to add to it too I think, but I don't know how to build up on existing classes.

Comment: Possibly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165317/how-can-i-extend-image-class/5165352#5165352

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You "extend" classes by subclassing them, as in

```
class MiniMath:
    def add(self, a, b):
        return a + b

class MoreMath(MiniMath):
    def sub(self, a, b):
        return a - b

mm = MoreMath()
print mm.add(1, 2) # 3
print mm.sub(1, 2) # -1
```

I suggest you read the Python tutorial first though.

Comment: Subclassing is not the best option to be tried first. Alternatives: (a) just define a function that operates on an Image instance. (b) Create a class that delegates necessary calls to a private Image instance.